# What is a authentic source of civil engineering BS graduation rate in united states in the last few year?

Tags: united-states, engineering

What is a authentic source from multi-institutional study of just civil engineering BS six years(preferable six year year, but otherwise it is okay) graduation rate in united states four year college and the research is conducted in one of the year in last five years?

If not, does somebody have access to this paper and snapshot a quarter of page from that paper for evidence?

http://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/(ASCE)EI.1943-5541.0000244

Comment: Have you considered trying to contact the author and ask for a pre-print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the American Society of Engineering Education's "Engineering by the Numbers" publications here: http://www.asee.org/papers-and-publications/publications/college-profiles

There are samples available online, but the full reports do have a cost.